# How to make ForeignKey to two tables in two different location

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 tables (users, user_shifts) in 2 different files but which are having a foreign key relationship to each other
In users, table shift field is a foreign key to shifts table and in shifts table created by field is a foreign key to the user's table.

But when I`m running the server it's raising an error that 
"cannot import users"

class Users(models.Model):

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
shift = models.ForeignKey(user_shifts)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'users'
```

class user_shifts(models.Model):

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
created_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now().date())
created_by = models.ForeignKey(users)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'user_shifts'
```

Comment: sounds like an issue with your imports - what `import` statements are you using in these files?

Comment: use `created_by = models.ForeignKey(Users)`

Answer (score 0):

@Troma78 have provided enough reason why your code is getting error. You mentioned class Name `Users` incorrect in `user_shifts` class. You should also use M2M field in `user_shifts` instead of two FKs in referring to each other.

There is also violation of coding styles in class naming. Refer to PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a circular import, when that happens python just stops running and claims it can't import something from the loop it was in.

You can fix this by passing a string to your ForeignKey fields, instead of the class, like so:

```
class User(models.Model):
    shift = models.ForeignKey(to='shifts_app.UserShift')

class UserShift(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(to='users_app.User')
```

And make sure to remove the circular import statements from your model files.

Comment: @angrysumit: yeah there's a lot going on in the example. But even when you use the correct class names this setup would result in a circular import.